# download, process, upload large number of s3 files with spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large amount of files (~500k hdf5) inside a s3 bucket which I need to process and reupload to another s3 bucket.

I am pretty new to such tasks, so I am not quite sure if my approach is correct here. I do the following:
I use boto to get the list of keys inside the bucket and parallelize it with spark:

```
s3keys = bucket.list()
data = sc.parallelize(s3keys)
data = data.map(lambda x: download_process_upload(x))
result = data.collect()
```

where `download_process_upload` is a function which downloads the file specified by the key, does some processing on it and re-uploads it to another bucket (returning 1 if everything was successful, and 0 if there was an error)
So in the end I could do

```
success_rate = sum(result) / float(len(s3keys))
```

I have read that spark `map` statements should be stateless, while my custom map function definitely is not stateless. It downloads the file to disk and then loads it into memory etc.

So is this the proper way to do such a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully used your methodology to download and process data from S3. I have not tried to upload the data from within a map statement. But, I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to read the file from s3, process it, and then upload it to a new location.

Also, you can save a few keystrokes and take the explicit lambda out of the map statement like this `data = data.map(download_process_upload)`